# Why is the break needed to stop the while loop in this function

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop, nested

Doing a Python3 exercise on nested loops to create this output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

But even though I set the condition to while i <= num, the function continued executing an infinite amount of time. I figured out that I needed to add the break, but I don't understand why the loop continued executing beyond the 1 time I called the function.

```
def triangle(num):
    i = 0
    while i <= num:
        for i in range(num):
            print(i*"*")
            i+=1
        break

triangle(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program you have is using the same loop variable `i` to iterate in both the `while` and `for` loop.

This get's confusing and thus to get the answer, they have introduced a random `break`.

This `break` is useless and can work without the outside `while` loop. You can just have the `for` loop and it will work:

```
def triangle(num):
    for i in range(num):
        print(i*"*")
```

So the break just gets you into the inner for loop and exits as soon as it's done.

To be honest, your program seems like a monkey patched program. Though it works, it's hard to read and maintain due to unusual logic.

> Now, how does the above code work?

Let's look at the problem at hand:

1. We have to create a triangular sequence of "*".
2. The number of "*" should be increasing and eventually equal to the number `num` sent as parameter.
3. In python, any string `x` multiplied by an integer `n` creates a string with `n` repetitions of `x`.

So if I have 
x = "abc"
newX = x*3 
print(newX) # prints abcabcabc

4. So all you need to do is to have a variable that can go from `1 to num` and multiply "*" and print the same. That has been indicated in the `for` loop and the print statement inside.

**Edit:**

If you're forced to use two loops, this is a good way to mimic it:

```
def triangle(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            print("*")
```

Or another weird way:

```
def triangle(n):
    i=0
    while(i<n):
        for j in range(n):
            print(i*"*")
            i += 1
```

Comment: thanks. I initially wrote 1 for loop, like you have above, but since the challenge was to use nested loops, I was trying to make that work. I can see how it's a little convoluted.

How would you write the nested loops?

Comment: Updated with two loops. If you find this to solve your question, could you mark it answered please.

Comment: Thanks for explaining